# The following 3x3 matrix has three real unique eigenvalues if and only if k is between what range?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find a range for possible values of k in matrix A so that it has three REAL and UNIQUE eigenvalues

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    -9 & 5 & 1 \\
    k & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I know that the characteristic equation of this matrix is:

\begin{equation*}
-\lambda^3+4\lambda^2-4\lambda+k=0
\end{equation*}

Where lambda represents the eigenvalues

I then used the following equation:

\begin{equation*}
-(\lambda-a)(\lambda-b)(\lambda-c)=0
\end{equation*}

Where a, b, and c are the three unique eigenvalues

To get that:
\begin{equation*}
a+b+c=4 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
abc=k
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-ab-ac-bc=-4
\end{equation*}

I have no idea what to do now.

Answer (score 2):

Given a cubic in the form 
$$f(x) = A x^3 + B x^2 + C x + D$$
the discriminant is defined as
$$D(f) = -27 A^2 D^2 + 18 ABCD - 4 A C^3 - 4 B^3 D + B^2 C^2.$$
$D(f)>0\iff \text{f has 3 distinct real roots}.$

We compute $D(f)$ for your cubic, with $A= -1, B= 4, C= -4, D =k$. This gives us
$$D(f) = -27k^2+32k >0\iff 0<k<32/27.$$

Answer (score 2):

The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) of that polynomial is $32k-27k^2$. So, your matrix will have three real distinct roots if and only if $32k-27k^2>0$, wich means that $k\in\left(0,\frac{32}{27}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=x^3-4x^2+4x$. Then
$$
f'(x)=3x^2-8x+4
$$
that vanishes at $2/3$ and $2$. Since
$$
f(2/3)=\frac{8}{27}-\frac{16}{9}+\frac{8}{3}=\frac{32}{27}
$$
and
$$
f(2)=0
$$
the equation $f(x)=k$ has three distinct solution if and only if
$$
0<k<\frac{32}{27}
$$

[image]